# Handling Double Quotes when creating soft links

Tags: r, double-quotes, single-quotes, mklink

I am trying to create some soft links with R and I am having a hard time with the single and double quotes.

Currently, I am doing this:
**system(paste("mklink /d '", paste0(softlink,"/input_data"),"' '", Inputfolder, "'", sep=""))**

Where:

softlink = "D:/users/target"
and  Inputfolder = "D:/users/input_data/"

However, when I am running it, it gives an error: "Running command 'mklink... had status 127'. Thus, I would like to get the following line, as I think this way it would work.

**"mklink /d "D:/users/target/input_data" "D:/users/input_data/""**

Unfortunately, whatever I have tried so far could not handle these quotes inside quotes. Could someone please help me to obtain the wanted line?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Double quotes can be add by using `\"`.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
path1 <- file.path(softlink, "/input_data")
path2 <- file.path(Inputfolder)
sprintf("mklink /d %s %s", normalizePath(path1), normalizePath(path2))
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. It just doubles the / .

Comment: Instead of system(), try shell(). Does it give an error? You might need to run R with administrator privileges()...

Comment: I tried it, and it gives the same error unfortunately. I opened RStudio as an admin. Besides that, do I need to do anything to run R as an admin?

Answer (score 1):

The standard way is to [escape](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Literal-constants) quotation marks:

```
system(paste("mklink /d \"", paste0(softlink,"/input_data"),"\" \"", Inputfolder, "\"", sep=""))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried this method already but then I will get the following thing as a result of the outer paste: "mklink /d \"D:/users/target/input_data/\" \"D:/users/input_data/\""  and if I apply a system to this it will not create the soft links.

Comment: How could I delete these unnecessary \s?:)

Comment: Just a thought: Your are on Windows, right? Shouldn't it be `D:\users\input_data\ ` then (mind the backward slashes)? Besides, if you don't have spaces in your directories, you don't need any `"` at all, imho.

Comment: Yes, I am on Windows, I tried the shell command as well but still it doesn't work. It gives execution failed with error code 1.   About the backward slashes, that was the first way I tried with D:\users\input_data\ as this is how I can manually create the soft links from the cmd, but it doesn't work from R. I am starting to think that is is a problem with admin privileages. DO you have any idea how I could solve this issue?

Comment: Well, mklink need admin rights ([see here](https://superuser.com/questions/124679/how-do-i-create-a-link-in-windows-7-home-premium-as-a-regular-user)). If it's a rights problem, you'd move over to [superuser](https://superuser.com).

Comment: Well, just to be clear, I can create the softlinks using the cmd window, so I have the admin rights to create them. My problem is that I cannot create them from R. And as I have to create around 30.000 softlinks I would like to automate the process in R:)